# Count duplicates and display order of occurence

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula, formulas

I am attempting to count the number of occurrences of each value within a column and then output the order in which it was found (top to bottom) with unsorted data. I have been unable to find a suitable formula to accomplish this task. Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Example:

```
Number     DuplicateIndex
50               1
20               1
30               1
10               1
30               2
40               1
30               3
50               2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try,

```
=countif(A$2:A2, A2)
```

, in B2 and fill down.

Answer (score 0):

Try,
In B2 and fill down

```
=unique(A2:A9)
```

In C2 and fill down

```
=countif(A$2:A9, B2)
```