# VBA: Count The Order Of Occurrence Of Duplicates

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, dictionary, duplicates

I have a dataset with a column of Purchase Orders. Many of the PO's are duplicates and I have a list of conditions that I am checking against, one of which, is the count of the duplicate PO's as they occur. I am having trouble discovering exactly how to modify my code to do so. Basically all I need is a something to count occurrences exactly like the formula in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37426298/count-duplicates-and-display-order-of-occurence)

So far I have code that counts the total of duplicate items per Key as follows:

```
Option Explicit
Sub DuplicateOccrencesCount()

    Dim Source_Array
    Dim dict As Object
    Dim i As Long
    Dim colIndex As Integer

    colIndex = 26

    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.dictionary")

     Source_Array = Sheet2.Range("A2").CurrentRegion.Value2


    For i = LBound(Source_Array, 1) To UBound(Source_Array, 1)
        If dict.Exists(Source_Array(i, colIndex)) Then
            dict.Item(Source_Array(i, colIndex)) = dict.Item(Source_Array(i, colIndex)) + 1
        Else
            dict.Add Source_Array(i, colIndex), 1
        End If
    Next i

    Sheet9.Range("A2").Resize(dict.Count, 1).Value = _
    WorksheetFunction.Transpose(dict.keys)
    Sheet9.Range("B2").Resize(dict.Count, 1).Value = _
    WorksheetFunction.Transpose(dict.items)

End Sub
```

However I need the number of occurrences per duplicate key in order of occurrence in the dictionary as it is built in order to match the functionallity of the `COUNTIF` in the [post mentioned above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37426298/count-duplicates-and-display-order-of-occurence). I thought of using something to find if the value at the current row index of `Source_array` within a loop is a duplicate and then increasing a counter Like so:

```
 Option Explicit
 Sub FindDupsInArray()
     Dim Source_Array
     Dim dict As Object
     Dim i As Long
     Dim colIndex As Integer
     Dim counter As Long

       counter = 0
       colIndex = 26

        Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.dictionary")

        Source_Array = Sheet2.Range("A2").CurrentRegion.Value2

        'On Error Resume Next
        For i = LBound(Source_Array, 1) To UBound(Source_Array, 1)
            If dict.Exists(Source_Array(i, colIndex)) Then
                counter = counter + 1
                Source_Array(i, 30) = counter
            End If
        Next i

        Sheet9.Range("A1").Resize(UBound(Source_Array, 1), _
            UBound(Source_Array, 2)) = Source_Array

    End Sub
```

However when the condition is true and the array is printed out to the sheet, `Source_Array(i,30)` is Blank for all rows.

Any thoughts, ideas, or answers would be greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE 1:** After trial and error, I came up with the following which I plan to make a function

```
Sub RunningCounts2()
  Dim dict As Object
  Dim i As Long
  Dim Source_Array

  Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

  Source_Array = Sheet2.Range("A2").CurrentRegion.Value2

  For i = LBound(Source_Array, 1) To UBound(Source_Array, 1)
     dict(Source_Array(i, 26)) = dict(Source_Array(i, 26)) + 1
     Source_Array(i, 30) = dict(Source_Array(i, 30))
  Next
  Sheet9.Range("B1").Resize(UBound(Source_Array, 1), UBound(Source_Array, 2)).Value = Source_Array  ' <-- writes results on next column. change as needed
End Sub
```

**UPDATE 2:** After several more hours of trial and error last night I came up with the following revision:

```
Sub GetRunningCounts()
  Dim dict As Object
  Dim i As Long
  Dim Source_Array, OutPut_Array

  Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

  Source_Array = Sheet2.Range("A2").CurrentRegion.Value2

  ReDim OutPut_Array(LBound(Source_Array, 1) To UBound(Source_Array, 1), 1 To 1)

  For i = LBound(Source_Array, 1) To UBound(Source_Array, 1)
     dict(Source_Array(i, 26)) = dict(Source_Array(i, 26)) + 1
     OutPut_Array(i, 1) = dict(Source_Array(i, 26))
  Next i

  Sheet9.Range("B1").Resize(UBound(OutPut_Array, 1)).Value = OutPut_Array

End Sub
```

Which I subsequently converted to a UDF as follows:

```
Function RunningCntOfOccsInArr(Source_Array As Variant, RowIndex As Long, ColIndex As Integer) As Long

Dim dict As Object               ' edit: corrected var spelling

    If IsArray(Source_Array) = False Then
        Exit Function

    ElseIf IsArrayAllocated(Source_Array) = False Then
        Exit Function

    ElseIf (RowIndex < LBound(Source_Array, 1)) Or (RowIndex > UBound(Source_Array, 1)) Then
        Exit Function

    ElseIf (ColIndex < LBound(Source_Array, 2)) Or (ColIndex > UBound(Source_Array, 2)) Then
        Exit Function

    End If

Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    ReDim OutPut_Array(LBound(Source_Array, 1) To UBound(Source_Array, 1), 1 To 1)

    For RowIndex = LBound(Source_Array, 1) To UBound(Source_Array, 1)
        dict(Source_Array(RowIndex, ColIndex)) = dict(Source_Array(RowIndex, ColIndex)) + 1
        OutPut_Array(i, 1)(RowIndex, 1) = dict(Source_Array(RowIndex, ColIndex))
    Next RowIndex

    RunningCntOfOccsInArr = OutPut_Array

End Function
```

Comment: if you just need COUNTIF, there is `WorksheetFunction.CountIf` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheetfunction.countif

Comment: Right, but `WorksheetFunction.CountIf` doesn't accept arrays which is what I need. I need something that mimics the functionality of `countif(A$2:A2, A2)`, but with the first argument as array with the second argument being a rowindex of an array. Basicallly, similar syntax as `countif(A$2:A2, A2)`, but with an array.

Comment: Did you just need to sort the output?

Comment: @rickmanalexander `WorksheetFunction.CountIf` does accept a `Range` object as the first parameter. Could you not just set a Range object first?

Comment: @RyanWildry I can't use a `Range` Object.  I am processing everything in memory, because I am copying a `recordset` from `SQL` to `Source_Array`, looking through the certain columns of the array, and then changing their values based on multiple conditions. One of which would need to use some function to get a count of the number of duplicates as the occur/ i.e.running total of the duplicates like so: `Mod(count of the number of duplicates as the occur/ i.e.running total of the duplicates) = 0`  and then categorize them as needed.

Comment: @rickmanalexander if you getting this from SQL, could you write a SQL Statement to get the result set you are after? E.g. `Select Count(*) as RecordCount, MyPoNumber From MyTable Group by MyPoNumber`?

Comment: @RyanWildry The PO's are already grouped in the `Select` statement that I am executing. Constraint given are something like the following:  If PO# i.e. `Len(Source)Array(i,26))=7` And duplicated POs in the same month/period 
And  `Instr(Source_Array(i,19))` Contains current or prior accrual
And `Source_Array(i,23) < 0` 
Then 
first trans: 
Tran Type= RO/Acc Adj 
Exp Category: to repair order from reversing entry 

second trans: 
Trans Type= payment
Exp Category = Repair Orders

Comment: @RyanWildry Edit to above: 
The PO's are already grouped in the `Select` statement that I am executing. The constraint given to me are something like the following:  If PO# i.e. `Len(Source)Array(i,26))=7` 
And duplicated POs in the same month/period Mod(i.e. count of the number of duplicates as the occur/ i.e.running total of the duplicates)
And  `Instr(Source_Array(i,19))` Contains current or prior accrual
And `Source_Array(i,23) < 0` 
More in following comment

Comment: @RyanWildry 
Then 
first trans with same PO: i.e. `Mod(count of the number of duplicates as the occur/ i.e.running total of the duplicates) = 0`
Tran Type= RO/Acc Adj 
Exp Category: to repair order from reversing entry 

second trans: i.e. `Mod(count of the number of duplicates as the occur/ i.e.running total of the duplicates) = 1`
Trans Type= payment
Exp Category = Repair Orders

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trial and error, I came up with the following:

```
Sub GetRunningCounts()
  Dim dict As Object
  Dim i As Long
  Dim Source_Array, OutPut_Array

  Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

  Source_Array = Sheet2.Range("A2").CurrentRegion.Value2

  ReDim OutPut_Array(LBound(Source_Array, 1) To UBound(Source_Array, 1), 1 To 1)

  For i = LBound(Source_Array, 1) To UBound(Source_Array, 1)
     dict(Source_Array(i, 26)) = dict(Source_Array(i, 26)) + 1
     OutPut_Array(i, 1) = dict(Source_Array(i, 26))
  Next i

  Sheet9.Range("B1").Resize(UBound(OutPut_Array, 1)).Value = OutPut_Array

End Sub
```

Which I subsequently converted to a UDF as follows:

```
Function RunningCntOfOccsInArr(ByRef Source_Array As Variant, ByRef RowIndex As Long, ByVal ColIndex As Integer) As Variant

 Dim dict As Object
 Dim OutPut_Array As Variant

    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    ReDim OutPut_Array(LBound(Source_Array, 1) To UBound(Source_Array, 1), 1 To 1)

    For RowIndex = LBound(Source_Array, 1) To UBound(Source_Array, 1)
        dict(Source_Array(RowIndex, ColIndex)) = dict(Source_Array(RowIndex, ColIndex)) + 1
        OutPut_Array(RowIndex, 1) = dict(Source_Array(RowIndex, ColIndex))
    Next RowIndex

    RunningCntOfOccsInArr = OutPut_Array

End Function
```

Here is an example of its use in a Sub Procedure. @TateGarringer Provided this implementation in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54150140/why-does-my-function-fail-where-a-subroutine-does-not) post.

```
Sub Test_GetRunningCounts()
  Dim i As Long
  Dim i2 As Long
  Dim Data_Array
  Dim returnArray() As Variant

  Application.ScreenUpdating = False

  Data_Array = Sheet1.Range("A2").CurrentRegion.Value2
    For i = LBound(Data_Array, 1) To UBound(Data_Array, 1)
        returnArray = RunningCntOfOccsInArr(Data_Array, i, 21)
        For i2 = LBound(returnArray) To UBound(returnArray)
            If returnArray(i2, 1) Mod 2 = 0 Then
                  Sheet2.Cells(i, 2).Value2 = "Even"
            Else
                  Sheet2.Cells(i, 2).Value2 = "Odd"
            End If
        Next i2
    Next i

    Sheet2.Range("A1").Resize(UBound(returnArray, 1)).Value = returnArray
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you use a second array?

```
Option Explicit
Sub DuplicateOccrencesCount()

Dim Source_Array
Dim result_array
Dim dict As Object
Dim i As Long
Dim colIndex As Integer

colIndex = 26

Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.dictionary")

 Source_Array = Sheet2.Range("A2").CurrentRegion.Value2
Redim result_array(lbound source_array,1) to ubound(source_array,1),1 to 1)


For i = LBound(Source_Array, 1) To UBound(Source_Array, 1)
    If dict.Exists(Source_Array(i, colIndex)) Then
        dict.Item(Source_Array(i, colIndex)) = dict.Item(Source_Array(i, colIndex)) + 1
    Else
        dict.Add Source_Array(i, colIndex), 1
    End If

    Result_array(I,1) = dict.Item(Source_Array(i, colIndex))
Next i

    Sheet9.Range("A2").Resize(dict.Count, 1).Value = _
    WorksheetFunction.Transpose(dict.keys)
    Sheet9.Range("B2").Resize(dict.Count, 1).value = result_array

End Sub
```

Sometimes I take a shortcut and grab two columns when I get the range values, then use the second column for the results.

Comment: I ended up doing just that at about 7PM last night before you posted this lol! See updates 1 and 2 in my post.