# Why does my function fail where a subroutine does not?

Tags: excel, vba, function, dictionary, multidimensional-array

I have a sub procedure that does the following:

1. Looks For Duplicates in an array using the `Dictionary` object
2. If a duplicate is found in the array, then provide a running count of that duplicate.

The following is an example of what my sub returns:

[image]

The Sub Works exactly as intended, so I translated it into a function, in order to use it in part of a program I am working on, but I cannot get my function to return results correctly.

Below is my Sub that works:

```
Sub GetRuningCounts()
  Dim dict As Object
  Dim i As Long
  Dim Source_Array, OutPut_Array

  Application.ScreenUpdating = False

  Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

  Source_Array = Sheet1.Range("A2").CurrentRegion.Value2

  ReDim OutPut_Array(LBound(Source_Array, 1) To UBound(Source_Array, 1), 1 To 1)
  'On Error Resume Next
  For i = LBound(Source_Array, 1) To UBound(Source_Array, 1)
     dict(Source_Array(i, 21)) = dict(Source_Array(i, 21)) + 1
     OutPut_Array(i, 1) = dict(Source_Array(i, 21))
  Next i

  Sheet2.Range("A1").Resize(UBound(OutPut_Array, 1)).Value = OutPut_Array

End Sub
```

**My UDF:**

```
Function RunningCntOfOccsInArr(ByRef Source_Array As Variant, ByRef RowIndex As Long,  ByVal ColIndex As Integer) As Long

 Dim ditc As Object
 Dim RowIndex As Long
 Dim OutPut_Array As Variant

    If IsArray(Source_Array) = False Then
        Exit Function

    ElseIf IsArrayAllocated(Source_Array) = False Then
        Exit Function

    ElseIf (ColIndex < LBound(Source_Array, 2)) Or (ColIndex > UBound(Source_Array, 2)) Then
        Exit Function

    End If

 Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    ReDim OutPut_Array(LBound(Source_Array, 1) To UBound(Source_Array, 1), 1 To 1)

    For RowIndex = LBound(Source_Array, 1) To UBound(Source_Array, 1)
        dict(Source_Array(RowIndex, ColIndex)) = dict(Source_Array(RowIndex, ColIndex)) + 1
        OutPut_Array(RowIndex, 1) = dict(Source_Array(RowIndex, ColIndex))
        RunningCntOfOccsInArr = OutPut_Array(RowIndex,1)
    Next RowIndex

End Function
```

**Example of Function in Sub:**

```
Sub Test_GetRunningCountss()
  Dim i As Long
  Dim Data_Array 

  Application.ScreenUpdating = False

  Data_Array = Sheet1.Range("A2").CurrentRegion.Value2
    For i = LBound(Data_Array, 1) To UBound(Data_Array, 1)
        If RunningCntOfOccsInArr(Data_Array, i, 21) Mod 2 = 0 Then 
              Sheet2.Cells(i, 2).Value2 = "Even"
        Else
              Sheet2.Cells(i, 2).Value2 = "Odd"
        End If

    Next i

End Sub
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: this can be done with a simple countifs() formula, if you are interested.

Comment: A function called from the sheet can only affect the cell from which it is called.

Comment: Generally speaking, you can (there are some exceptions, let's not digress) only use a function to *return* a value to the function's caller. Also worth noting: you cannot (again, generally and for good reason) use a UDF to manipulate the environment. I'm not entirely sure what you're doing here, but you're assigning a return value to the function within a loop, and that seems problematic. Should `Output_Array` be the function's return value?

Comment: @ScottCraner Oh I know. In fact, it would be `countif(A$2:A2, A2)`. Alas, this is reading results from a large `recordset` array is going to be used in a very small piece of a complex program.

Comment: @DavidZemens The goal of the Function is to assign the return value to an index of the `OutPut_Array`, then within my sub, I want to take that returned value and determine if it is even or odd for each index of the array. From there I would execute statements based of the results of my if statement.So to answer your question, yes, but only one `RowIndex` of the `OutPut_Array` at a time.

Comment: There's a typo in your function Dim ditc As Object   > dict

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks to me like `RunningCntOfOccsInArr = OutPut_Array(RowIndex,1)` is only returning the very last value of your `For Next` Loop. What I would recommend is redefining your function as an Array by way of Variant data type and changing your `For Next` Loop to

```
Function RunningCntOfOccsInArr(ByRef Source_Array As Variant, ByRef RowIndex As Long,  ByVal ColIndex As Integer) As Variant
'....Other Code Here....
For RowIndex = LBound(Source_Array, 1) To UBound(Source_Array, 1)
    dict(Source_Array(RowIndex, ColIndex)) = dict(Source_Array(RowIndex, ColIndex)) + 1
    OutPut_Array(RowIndex, 1) = dict(Source_Array(RowIndex, ColIndex))
Next RowIndex
RunningCntOfOccsInArr = OutPut_Array
```

And in your Sub calling it you'd need to define an array to hold your function value (so it's not called every time) and a nested loop to loop through those returned values.

```
Sub Test_GetRunningCountss()
  Dim i As Long
  Dim i2 as Long
  Dim Data_Array
  Dim returnArray() As Variant

  Application.ScreenUpdating = False

  Data_Array = Sheet1.Range("A2").CurrentRegion.Value2
    For i = LBound(Data_Array, 1) To UBound(Data_Array, 1)
        returnArray = RunningCntOfOccsInArr(Data_Array, i, 21)
        For i2 = LBound(returnArray) to UBound(returnArray)
            If returnArray(i2, 1) Mod 2 = 0 Then 
                  Sheet2.Cells(i2, 2).Value2 = "Even"
            Else
                  Sheet2.Cells(i2, 2).Value2 = "Odd"
            End If
        Next i2
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: I changed the `i2` to `i` In `Sheets2.Cells(i2,2).Value2` and that did it! I can't thank you enough man!

Comment: Oops, that's my bad. Thanks for pointing that out, I've edited the answer to reflect that. Glad to have helped!

Comment: No worries my friend, I am just glad it works! I wrote [this  post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54079904/vba-count-the-order-of-occurrence-of-duplicates) the other day along the lines of this issue, but ended answering the question myself and I posted my original function there. I just went and edited it to include your `'Sub' implementation and gave you credit for how to use my function. Blessings man!